# How to fetch big data in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

Csv Link:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv

Hello, I need to import the above csv file, but I need to do it from this link to be up to date. When I take this data and use pinia for storage data, about 700mb is added to my memory usage every time I refresh the page. Since I don't know the backend, I need to fetch and use the data like this.

What should I do so that the memory usage does not increase every time I refresh the page?

Pinia Code:

```js
import {defineStore} from "pinia";
import {computed, ref} from "vue";

export const useCovidDataStore = defineStore('covidData', () => {
    const data = ref(null)
    const loaded = ref(false)
    const selectedCountry = ref('Germany')

    function setData(veri) {
        data.value = veri
    }
    function setCountry(country) {
        selectedCountry.value = country
    }
    function setLoaded() {
        loaded.value = !loaded.value

    }

    const getData = computed(() => data.value)
    const getLoaded = computed(() => loaded)
    const getSelectedCountry = computed(()=>selectedCountry)
    return {data, setData, getData, setLoaded, getLoaded, loaded,selectedCountry,setCountry,getSelectedCountry}
})
```

Data Code:

```js
Papa.parse("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv", {
    download: true,
    header: true,
    complete: function(results) {
      const groupedByLocation = results.data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
        if (!acc[obj.location]) {
          acc[obj.location] = [];
        }
        acc[obj.location].push(obj);
        return acc;
      }, {});
      store.setData(groupedByLocation)

    }
    
  })
```

Comment: Probably the best way is to add a BFF that allows pagination and maybe even graphql so you really only load the data you need in the front end.

Comment: @Thomas GraphQL is not that trivial to setup initially (regarding the performance) and can solve some over-fetching for sure, but will not solve an issue solved by pagination by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a huge amount of data you can either:

- use some pagination to get only some chunks and not the whole thing
- use a middleware backend/serverless function to do that work on a more appropriate place

No other magic sauce. `.slice`'ing on the frontend will not make the loading of the page more performant, just reduce the DOM overhead of injecting all of those nodes.

Memoization can also help, but not on the initial load.

Comment: So why does the amount of memory used increase every time I refresh the page? Adds new data without deleting old data from memory?

Comment: @YunusEmreArslan if you have an increased memory spike when you hard refresh your page, that means that have a memory leak somewhere. Quite common in an SSR context. You should have the same (not a huge amount but still) if refreshing with a smaller subset of data tbh. There is something about `ref` and that subject in the docs if I'm not mistaken.